# Can I apply for a new Schengen visa while holding a valid single-entry Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a single entry visa for Italy from 03/07/15 to 01/08/15 with 15 days validity. I also want to visit Spain and France in same month. I will be back from Italy on 07/07/15, So can I apply for another Schengen country in July month or I have to wait till 01/08/15?

Comment: You can apply for another visa to be forward-dated to start on 2/8/15 while your current visa is running.  Or if your circumstances are *exceptional*, you can *try* for an extension of your existing visa. Neither option is straight-forward but the first is usually better.

Comment: Thanks Gayot Fow....for Help. But i need to travel back in July..:(. I was suggested by my colleague that i can get this VISA cancelled once i am back from Italy and then can reapply for a new country. Another one for you if you can help.. will a cancelled Visa create issue for my future travels?

Comment: That's fine also.  Tell them you want a "voluntary revocation".  These are always done without prejudice.

Comment: Great!! and a big thanks to you... really helpful. I will just find out the process of how to get this cancellation done.

Answer (score -4):

A short stay Schengen visa entitles the holder to visit the Schengen countries for tourism, visiting friend/family, business etc., up to 90 days within a 180 day period from the date of first entry. the stay may be either continuous or several visits depending upon whether the visa is single or multiple entry

***single entry visa***

Allows uninterrupted stay. Once the person departs the Schengen territory, he/she can`t enter again without obtaining a new visa after the time of visa expires.

Comment: How does this answer the question?